# O que são os termos "Cascade" e "Classifier" em relação a visão computacional?

Tags: terminologia, opencv, aprendizagem-de-máquina, visão-computacional

Sempre quando eu leio [algo a respeito do OpenCV e visão computacional](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html) me surgem dois termos que são *Cascade* e *Classifier*, esses termos me deixam bem confuso em relação do que eles podem ser ou significar.

Portanto, eu gostaria de que fosse esclarecido as seguintes dúvidas:

1. O que é Cascade?
2. O que é Classifier?
3. Há diferenças entre Cascade e Classifier ou ambos representam as mesmas coisas?

Comment: Na verdade acho que "Cascade Classifier" é uma coisa só no contexto, classificador de cascata, então não são diferentes mas sim algo como *"classificador em cascata"*, ou seja algo que irá classificar em cascata algo, mas não entendo bem o contexto ali para conseguir explicar algo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento as vezes eles aparecem juntos mas tem momentos que parecem separados com significados diferentes, isso no contexto do OpenCV e visão computacional.

Comment: Encontrei sobre ambos em algumas leituras, realmente vale a pena falar deles, o +1 esta garantido, favoritei pra acompanhar :)

Comment: Eu dei um  -1 porque não achei mt útil a pergunta. Vou me reservar no motivo, mas vou acompanhar.

Comment: @ÐvÐ não achou util porque seria sobre [tag:terminologia]? Esse tipo de assunto me parece bem aceito na comunidade, até mesmo você fez uma pergunta sobre terminologia, claro que o motivo pode ser outro, só estou tentando presumir algo para ajudar o autor a melhorar a pergunta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. Não, eu gosto muito de terminologia. Mas achei a pergunta meio sem sentido. Estive lendo sobre e me pareceu que "Cascade classifier" é uma coisa só, seria, "classificador em cascata".. então, na minha opinião, a pergunta ficou sem sentido ao perguntar o que é uma coisa ou outra. Pra mim seria mais interessante (minha opinião) se a pergunta fosse algo do tipo: "O que significa Cascade Classifier"...

Comment: @ÐvÐ sim, pelo que li, como no meu primeiro comentário é uma coisa só nesse contexto, mas o Gato, o Luiz e Ramaral talvez, sejam os unicos que conheço que dominem este assunto, fora que o Gato conversou comigo e disse que na verdade essa pergunta servirá de rebote para outra, resumindo ele talvez já saiba a correlação das palavras dentro deste contexto

Comment: @ÐvÐ pergunta editada

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Classificadores

Um classificador é um sistema computacional que, tendo alguns dados de entrada que caracterizam um exemplo de algo, classifica esse algo dentre algumas opções.

O uso de classificadores na Visão Computacional é o mais diverso. Exemplos ilustrativos famosos são aquelas máquinas que [separam tomates maduros de verdes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rdsyRvUH9sA) ou [grãos de café maduros de verdes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lGFefT5hvU), comumente com base em análise de cor. Eles também são usados na detecção de intrusos, de [focos de incêndio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8578/como-identificar-regi%C3%B5es-de-calor-em-imagens-t%C3%A9rmicas), [reconhecimento de faces](https://www.superdatascience.com/opencv-face-recognition/) (identidade), [detecção de nudez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104656/algoritmo-para-detectar-nudez-com-boa-precis%C3%A3o), [reconhecer dígitos](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html), e por aí vai.

Porém, classificadores também são úteis em muitas outras tarefas que não envolvem processamento de imagens. Podem, por exemplo, ser utilizados para classificar uma ação como compra ou venda com base em seu histórico de transação, um jogador como novato ou especialista com base em seu histórico de jogo, flores em diferentes categorias com base em suas características físicas, diferentes estruturas ortográficas em uma sentença escrita com base apenas no texto, diferentes comandos de voz com base em variações de frequência de voz, e por aí vai.

Esse termo é tradicionalmente utilizado na [Inteligência Artificial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86869/o-que-%C3%A9-intelig%C3%AAncia-artificial), em especial na [Aprendizagem de Máquina](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113343/qual-%C3%A9-a-defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-aprendizado-de-m%C3%A1quina-machine-learning). O que acontece é que a Aprendizagem de Máquina está bastante popular hoje em dia, principalmente no processamento de imagens, e pode gerar a confusão de que o termo Classificador é exclusivo dessa área. Para saber como funciona um classificador, dê uma olhada [nesta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40135/explicar-o-algoritmo-svr) e também [nesta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192098/como-funciona-uma-rede-neural-artificial) outra pergunta.

### *Cascade*

*Cascade* (cascata, em português) ou *Haar Cascade* é o "apelido" de um famoso algoritmo de busca de objetos em imagens, cujo nome oficial é [Algoritmo de Viola-Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework) (devido aos nomes dos autores).

Esse algoritmo utiliza máscaras (as chamadas [Haar Features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar-like_feature)) para caracterizar um objeto por meio de variações de luminosidade (principalmente em bordas). As máscaras capturam essas variações em diferentes amplitudes e direções, e os valores que caracterizam um certo tipo de objeto (uma face inteira ou só um olho, por exemplo) são aprendidas com um algoritmo de aprendizagem de máquina chamado [AdaBoost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost) para gerar **vários classificadores**, um para cada Haar Feature. Uma vez que esses classificadores são produzidos - isto é, treinados a partir de imagens de exemplo (no caso do Cascade, com imagens positivas - que têm o objeto - e negativas - que não têm o objeto), ele encontra o objeto em uma nova imagem executando os vários mini classificadores "em cascata" (e daí o apelido do algoritmo):

1. O algoritmo define um tamanho de janela, escala as Haar Features para esse tamanho, e varre a imagem sendo buscada segundo essa janela. (É muito mais eficiente escalar as features do que a imagem, até porque as features já podem ser mantidas pré-escaladas).
2. Em cada janela, o algoritmo seleciona e executa um dos mini classificadores (para uma dada feature) com base nos valores de pixel na imagem sob aquela janela.
3. Se a feature retorna falso (isto é, não é o objeto do ponto de vista dela), o algoritmo segue para a próxima janela. Se acabaram as janelas, ele conclui que não tem o objeto procurado na imagem.
4. Se a feature retorna true (isto é, é o objeto do ponto de vista dela), o algoritmo passa para o próximo classificador e repete a partir do passo 2. Se não há mais mini classificadores para executar, o algoritmo conclui pois encontrou o objeto naquela janela.

A imagem a seguir ilustra esse processo no [detector de faces do OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html) (as features são reproduzidas da página do OpenCV).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O uso do AdaBoost é importante por desempenho, já que esse algoritmo procura iterativamente na imagem com janelas de vários tamanhos. Por isso ele é capaz de encontrar objetos com bastante robustez em diferentes escalas (isto é, com diferentes tamanhos). Um ponto importante é que a sua acurácia em encontrar objetos **depende fortemente** das imagens utilizadas no treinamento. Se forem utilizadas imagens com o objeto em apenas uma orientação no treinamento, o algoritmo não será capaz de identificar o objeto em outras orientações (por exemplo, um algoritmo de [detecção de bananas](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html) treinado com bananas na horizontal não irá reconhecê-las em qualquer outra orientação além dessa).

### Conclusão

**Definitivamente** os termos não querem dizer a mesma coisa. Classificadores são algoritmos utilizados para a predição de classes em dados de entrada. O algoritmo de Viola-Jones, ou Haar Cascade, ou só Cascade, é um algoritmo de detecção de objetos, que utiliza diversos classificadores.